# Could not find linecache19-0.5.13 in any of the sources on Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed Ruby, if I run

```
ruby -v
```

I see:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

If I run in my app dir

```
rails server
```

output:

```
←[31mCould not find multi_json-1.3.2 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

Running

```
bundle install
```

this error appears:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find linecache19-0.5.13 in any of the sources
```

what's the problem?

Comment: I this this may have something to do with `ruby-debug`.  What version of `ruby-debug` are you using?  Can you paste your Gemfile?

Comment: Also, what version of `Rails` are you on?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like `linecache19-0.5.13` has been released yet.

The current version is `0.5.12` according to [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/linecache19).

Comment: Thank you for that github link to the linecache19 repo. This is what I used in my Gemfile to install the required gems through bundler: `gem 'linecache19', '>= 0.5.13', :git => 'https://github.com/robmathews/linecache19-0.5.13.git'; gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '>= 0.11.30.pre10'; gem 'ruby-debug-ide', '>= 0.4.17.beta14'`

Comment: So I published this as linecache19-patched. You should be able to use it normally now. I no longer user ruby 1.9.x (moved on a long time ago), so maybe someone else wants this gem?

Answer (score 2):

Based on user154184's response above, I got it to work using these commands below. It basically downloads the binary gem file for
linecache19 from rubyforge and install the gem using that binary gem file.

```
> curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
> gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
```

Comment: I believe this is the most appropriate solution until 0.5.13 is published to rubygems.org (as cited by @Azolo)

Answer (score 1):

See this gist: https://gist.github.com/1848409 to add the correct dependencies for ruby-debug19 with 1.9.3 etc

Answer (score 1):

Running `bundle update` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

are you behind a firewall?

can you manually install "linecache" by running "$ gem install linecache"?

if neither works, please make sure you can reach the internet using "gem".  see gem's "-p" option.

Comment: I'm on win 7 it outputs: ERROR:  Invalid option: -p.  See 'gem --help'.