# Why would bundle install try to install linecache19?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, linecache

I am trying to run "bundle install". It tries to install linecache19 version 0.5.13 which is not yet released. I can't find the linecache19 gem in Gemfile. Its getting installed as a dependency of some other gem. I would like to know what linecache19 gem is used for and who requires it.

Comment: Potential duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474872/could-not-find-linecache19-0-5-13-in-any-of-the-sources-on-windows-7-x64

Comment: i would like to know the use of linecache19 more than fixing my bundle install issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `gem dependency GEMNAME` on each of the gems in your gemfile (and possibly on their dependencies) to see who is requiring linecache19 0.5.13.

Maybe someone else will know of a way to search the whole dependency tree in one go.

Comment: `gem list | sed s/\ \(.*\)// | gem dependency`